# Is it safe to visit the pyramids near Cairo in 2016?

Tags: safety, event-based-effects, egypt

We are planning a holiday in December to Egypt and found a very good all inclusive deal for a week's stay in Hurghada. However, this doesn't include a visit to the pyramids.

I would not like to miss an opportunity to visit the pyramids and would like to know how is the current situation in Cairo.

Is it safe for tourists to plan a visit to the pyramids? By safe, I mean if the political situation in Cairo is stable without any protests and if tourists can visit Cairo without expecting any disruptions to normal life. My search online directed me to certain suggestions about tourists asked to be careful etc., but all this from 2013. I would like to know the current situation in Cairo.

Comment: edited my question @Flimzy

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that it will not be safe by then. But truth will be revealed by NYE 2016.

Comment: Just now a friend of me visiting Cairo posted an update on facebook that for some reason his all photography things were confiscated at airport.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe for tourists to visit Cairo and Giza Pyramids, Cairo is in the green zone as per the [UK Gov Travel Advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/egypt)

It is recommended to have pre-booked trip to Giza Pyramids and it is highlighted in [UK travel safety and security for Cairo](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/egypt/safety-and-security) as well, and the risk here is not related to politics and protests or even terrorism, the risk is people who work in tourism industry are trying to make more money to cover the business by any mean.

Most of visitors spend one day in Cairo to visit Giza Pyramids and then travel to other destinations like Luxur, Aswan, Hurghada and Sharm Elsheikh.

The trip from airport to Giza Pyramids takes [around 90 minutes via high way](https://goo.gl/maps/Ghy2LiEKQiE2) which is very far from the city center.